# Nothingtoinstall redirects to webapps.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, domain-name

Now if you type in `nothingtoinstall.com` in your URL you will be directed to `webapps.stackexchange.com`.

Isn't this a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. See the answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webapps.stackexchange.com versus Nothingtoinstall.com](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com)

Comment: The 2010 blog post about this: [Domain Names: The Wrong Question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/05/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)