# Giving the community blog a name

Tags: discussion, blog

If it's even allowed or possible, should the [Web Apps blog](http://webapps.blogoverflow.com/) be able to name itself?

Something like the following, with a tag line that makes it clear again what it is to those dropping by:

> ## Nothing to Install
>
> The Web Applications Stack Exchange community blog

Looking at [other community blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs) already posting away, none appear to have their own "name" unless their parent site also has a custom domain name.

("Nothing to Install" [was at one time](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com) what this site would have been named for those curious.)

Or do you think the mouthy "Web Applications Stack Exchange community blog" is good enough?

Comment: At the moment, due to how we setup themes for the blogs, custom names aren't much of an option yet - the theme takes the name of the site and sticks "Community Blog" at the end (there'll be an appropriate theme on Web Apps soon enough, Jin finished making it last night). Our current future plans don't seem to look custom-name friendly, so I don't want to raise people's hopes. That said, I also don't feel it's helpful for me to stifle this discussion, so if y'all still want to toss names back-and-forth, no harm doin'.

Comment: Christianity has "Eschewmenical" in the TITLE tag, so is it okay for us to put one there, should we come up with one?

Comment: Yes, that's allowed. We can put Nothing to Install there now lest y'all want summat else instead.